# How can I load the values into an array first then print it using the main body?

Tags: java

I was trying to solve a machine problem which required me to do:

> Write a program that loads array list with N random integers (range:
> 1000-10000). Load into array prime all  prime integers in list. Load
> into array even all integers in array list whose sum of its digits is
> even. Load into  array odd all integers in array list whose sum of its
> digits is odd. Print the 3 arrays. Display also the highest  and
> lowest prime numbers. Do not sort array prime. The program should also
> meet the following requirements:
>
> - Validate N; N>20
> - Create at least 4 user-defined methods and used it in the program.
> - Use of static variables is not allowed except for Scanner/Random object.
> - Your program should execute for as long as the user wants to continue.
> - Use of Java Collections (Arraylist, Linklist, etc) is not allowed.

After doing the code for a bit, I thought I was about to finish however I realized a grave error within my coding, after checking, it seems like instead of being stored in an array first, the numbers were instantly and directly printed out meaning that the code did not fulfill the loading of the numbers into their respective arrays before printing, how am I able to print the different arrays (RandList, Prime, Even, Odd) inside of the main function? (I am still quite new to coding so much help will be appreciated)

This is the code that I have written

```
   public class Diagnostic {
    
    static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    static Random rnd = new Random();
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n;
        String cont = "no";
        do{
            
            do{
            System.out.print("Please Enter A Number Greater Than 20:");
            n = scan.nextInt();
            scan.nextLine();
            }while(n < 20);
        
            int[] Randlist = new int[n];
            int[] prime = new int[n];
            int[] even = new int[n];
            int[] odd = new int[n];

            System.out.println("Here are the List of Random Numbers:");
            StartList(Randlist);

            System.out.printf("\n");

            System.out.println("Here are the List of Prime Numbers as well as the Highest and Lowest Prime     Number:");
            StartPrime(Randlist, prime);

            System.out.printf("\n");

            System.out.println("Here are the List of Odd and Even Numbers");
            CheckOddEven(Randlist, odd, even, n);
        
        System.out.print("Would You Like to Continue the Program? (yes/no):");
        cont = scan.nextLine();

        } while(!cont.equalsIgnoreCase("no"));
        System.out.print("The Program Has Stopped");
}
    public static void StartList(int[] Randlist){
    for(int i = 0; i< Randlist.length; i++){ 
    Randlist[i] = rnd.nextInt(9001) + 1000;
        System.out.printf("Random Numbers: %d\n", Randlist[i]);
    }
}
    public static boolean CheckPrime(int num){
    int j;
        boolean CheckPrime = true;
                for(j=2; j<=Math.sqrt(num); j++) {
                    if(num % j == 0) { 
                        CheckPrime = false;
        }
    }
        return CheckPrime;
}        
    public static void StartPrime(int[] Randlist, int[] prime){
        int f = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < Randlist.length; i++){
        if(CheckPrime(Randlist[i])) {
            prime[f++] = Randlist[i]; 
   }
  }
        int highest = prime[0]; 
        int lowest = prime[0];

        for(int i=1; i<f; i++) {
            if(prime[i] > highest){
            highest = prime[i]; 
    }
            if(prime[i] < lowest){ 
            lowest = prime[i];
    }
  }

        System.out.println("Highest Prime Number: " + highest);  
        System.out.println("Lowest Prime Number: " + lowest);
        
        for(int i = 0; i < f; i++){
        System.out.printf("Prime Numbers: %d\n", prime[i]);
  }
 }  
    public static void CheckOddEven(int[] Randlist, int[] odd, int[] even, int n){
        int i, j = 0, k = 0, sum, hold, oddcount = 0, evencount = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
        hold = Randlist[i];
        sum = 0;
        while(hold > 0){
            sum += (hold % 10);
            hold /= 10;
        }
        if (sum % 2 == 1){
            odd[j] = Randlist[i];
            j += 1;
            oddcount += 1;
        } 
        else{
            even[k] = Randlist[i];
            k+=1;
            evencount += 1;
        }
    }
    for (j = 0; j < oddcount; j++){
        System.out.printf("Odd Numbers: %d\n", odd[j]);
    }
    System.out.printf("\n");
    for (k = 0; k < evencount; k++){
        System.out.printf("Even Numbers: %d\n", even[k]);
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your code has inconsistent/incorrect indentation, which makes it difficult to read. If it looks OK in your IDE, you may be mixing tabs and spaces. I suggest you fix that to make it easier for people to quickly read & understand your code.

Comment: Make your methods to return arrays. And they will not have to be `void` anymore.

Comment: That's it in a nutshell -- don't have your methods call println and be declared to return `void`. Instead, have them print nothing and return something of use, here, have at least one return an array of int, and then use the return value obtained by calling the method.